# HowTo correctly close QDialog when main windows is hidden?

Tags: c++, qt

I have some kind of dilemma.

I'm using:

- MSVS 2008
- Qt 4.7.3 (with Qt VS Add-in 1.1.9)

I wrote small Qt application, base on `QMainWindow` class, where also exists *settings* dialog (`QDialog`). Every works fine in GUI mode. After that I started to change my project to make it visible only in *tray*. Just comment in main.cpp `show()` method, like this:

```
MainWindow w;
//w.show();

return app.exec();
```

But from tray, I need to launch *settings* dialog, which is implemented in mainwindow.h/.cpp files. I added to tray menu action (`QAction`) which is starts that *settings* dialog. And here comes the unexpected problem: when I tried to close this *settings* dialog with [ X ] close button (in top right corner) my **app closed**!

Here is the action slot:

```
void MainWindow::onOpenSettingsDlgClicked()
{
     SettingsDlg dlg( this );
     dlg.exec();
}
```

I have tried to reimplement `virtual reject()` method for the *settings* dialog class, and set there only `hide()` function, but that solution not helped.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks you!

Comment: What means "solution not helped" - is the app still closing? Can you show the reject() implementation? You are not by chance calling the base implementation there?

Comment: Did you have a connection for signal `QApplication::lastWindowClosed()` (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qapplication.html#lastWindowClosed)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should turn off the `quitOnLastWindowClosed` property which is turned on by default as defined in the doc (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop)

This said, you'll have to handle the termination of your QApplication yourself, maybe with an [quit] entry in the tray menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just found another option which seems better is to override closeEvent of the QDialog to only hide it.

```
void PrefDialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    this->hide();
    event->ignore();
}
```

I found this seems better because it doesn't change the global application behaviour.